# Python Plotnine (ggplot) add mean line per color to plot?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, plotnine

Using plotnine in python, I'd like to add dashed horizontal lines to my plot (a scatterplot, but preferably an answer compatible with other plot types) representing the mean for every color separately. I'd like to do so without manually computing the mean values myself or adapting other parts of the data (e.g. adding columns for color values etc).

Additionally, the original plot is generated via a function (`make_plot` below) and the mean lines are to be added afterwards, yet need to have the same color as the points from which they are derived.

Consider the following as a minimal example;

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotnine import *


df  = pd.DataFrame( { 'MSE': [0.1,  0.7,  0.5,  0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.8, 0.9 ,1.0, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9 ],
                        'Size': ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL'],
                        'Number': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]  } )

def make_plot(df, var_x, var_y, var_fill) :
    plot = ggplot(df) + aes(x='Number', y='MSE', fill = 'Size') + geom_point()
    return plot

plot = make_plot(df, 'Number', 'MSE', 'Size')
```

I'd like to add 4 lines, one for each `Size`. The exact same can be done in R using `ggplot`, as shown by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29473955/ggplot-add-two-mean-lines-for-plot). Adding `geom_line(stat="hline", yintercept="mean", linetype="dashed")` to `plot` however results in an error `PlotnineError: "'stat_hline' Not in Registry. Make sure the module in which it is defined has been imported."` that I am unable to resolve.

Answers that can resolve the aforementioned issue, or propose another working solution entirely, are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by first defining the means as a vector and then pass it to your function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotnine import *
from random import randint



df  = pd.DataFrame( { 'MSE': [0.1,  0.7,  0.5,  0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.8, 0.9 ,1.0, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9 ],
                        'Size': ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL'],
                        'Number': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]  } )

a = df.groupby(['Size'])['MSE'].mean()  ### Defining yuor means
a = list(a)

def make_plot(df, var_x, var_y, var_fill):
    plot = ggplot(df) + aes(x='Number', y='MSE', fill = 'Size') + geom_point()+ geom_hline(yintercept =a,linetype="dashed")
    return plot

plot = make_plot(df, 'Number', 'MSE', 'Size')
```

which gives:

[image]

Note that two of the lines coincide:

```
a = [0.6666666666666666, 0.5, 0.4666666666666666, 0.6666666666666666]
```

To add different colors to each dashed line, you can do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotnine import *


df  = pd.DataFrame( { 'MSE': [0.1,  0.7,  0.5,  0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.8, 0.9 ,1.0, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9 ],
                        'Size': ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL'],
                        'Number': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]  } )

### Generate a list of colors of the same length as your categories (Sizes)
color = []
n = len(list(set(df.Size)))

for i in range(n):
    color.append('#%06X' % randint(0, 0xFFFFFF))
######################################################

def make_plot(df, var_x, var_y, var_fill):
    plot = ggplot(df) + aes(x='Number', y='MSE', fill = 'Size') + geom_point()+ geom_hline(yintercept =list(df.groupby(['Size'])['MSE'].mean()),linetype="dashed", color =b)
    return plot

plot = make_plot(df, 'Number', 'MSE', 'Size')
```

which returns:

[image]

Comment: It's almost exactly what I need. As listed here, I'd have to pass `a` as an argument to `make_plot`, which wouldn't be too much of a stretch in my case.
I'm still searching for a way to color the dashed lines in the same color as the points, as adding `color = "Size" ` does not do the trick.

Comment: If `b` could either be extracted from the plot itself or be set to whatever default color palette ggplot uses (with changing amount of colors required), then this would be a viable answer. Manually picking colors that is not a scalable solution.

Comment: @Mathijs I updated my answer with a random color generator. It creates a list of colors that matches the lenght of your list of sizes.